# What is a "control character in ASCII form"?

Tags: assembly, emu8086

I am taking Microprocessors course and I have an issues to solve, so I can finish my code.

[image: This is my project]

I wrote a code that can compare and count the first 7 requirements.

But the problems are:

1. How can I read text file from my computer by letting the user enter the name of the text file? (what is the interrupt ?)
2. What is the (All other control characters in ASCII form.) ?

Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

1. http://www.ctyme.com/intr/cat-010.htm lists DOS system calls.  You could also google up an example of opening + reading a file with `int 21h` DOS system calls.
2. Control characters might mean anything that's not one of the other 7 categories, or they might mean ASCII codes 1..31 (http://jkorpela.fi/chars/c0.html).  Or 0..31, if you count control-space.